# How is the story structured in LA Noire?

Tags: la-noire

NO SPOILERS PLEASE

I just bought the complete edition of LA Noire. I am a little confused as to how the games story is structured. I am playing the normal missions in the story mode and I am at a case called the "The Consul's Car"

But if I exit the game and go to the main menu I see there is a cases option in the menu, where I can select my cases. I can obviously play my previous cases but I can also cases a few cases from "Vice" and "Arson", they start out totally random and I can't make out how this fits into the game.

Is the game suppose to work this way?

Comment: If I recall correctly, The Consul's Car was a DLC case. DLC cases were incorporated into the main game as just another case in their respective areas (vice, arson, homicide, etc.), but could also be played freely from the main menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story of L.A. Noire is structured as following:

1. Patrol Desk
2. Traffic Desk
3. Homicide Desk
4. Vice Desk
5. Arson Desk

In that order, which represents Cole Phelps' career within the police force.

---

As for why you can play cases from the Vice and Arson Desks, I'm not sure. My guess is that they're DLC cases and you somehow managed to gain access to them early.

While playing the game on PS3 (no DLCs) I've never been able to access any of the future cases.

Currently, I'm playing the game on Switch. I'm at the end of the Homicide Desk and I still can't access any of the cases from the Vice or Arson Desks.

Therefore, I'm going to assume that the game isn't supposed to work this way. Or maybe the Complete Edition works differently from the versions I've played.